# How to make heatmap of half triangled correlation matrix containing colored dendrogram?

Tags: r, matrix, plot, visualization, dendrogram

I have a ranked correlation matrix.
I wanted to visualize the half triangled correlation matrix with colored dendrogram heatmap.2 function of "gplots", where I failed because I do not know how to do it.
then I tried R packages "corrgram" and "corrplot" where I can visualize half triangled correlation matrix but can not draw dendrogram indicating clustering of samples on the basis of spearman's correlation

my best try is with corrgram package

```
    panel.shadeNtext <- function (x, y, corr = NULL, col.regions, ...) 
            {
                 corr <- cor(x, y, use = "pair")
              results <- cor.test(x, y, alternative = "two.sided")
                  est <- results$p.value
                stars <- ifelse(est < 5e-4, "***", 
                          ifelse(est < 5e-3, "**", 
                          ifelse(est < 5e-2, "*", "")))
                  ncol <- 14
                   pal <- col.regions(ncol)
               col.ind <- as.numeric(cut(corr, breaks = seq(from = -0.8, to = 1.2, 
                   length = ncol + 1), include.lowest = TRUE))
                      usr <- par("usr")
     rect(usr[1], usr[3], usr[2], usr[4], col = pal[col.ind], 
                             border = NA)
     box(col = "white")
     on.exit(par(usr))
      par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
                      r <- formatC(corr, digits = 2, format = "f")
                cex.cor <- .8/strwidth("-X.xx")
                  fonts <- ifelse(stars != "", 1,1)
                                                  # option 1: stars:
                     text(0.5, 0.4, paste0(stars), cex = cex.cor)
                                                  # option 2: bolding:
                    #text(0.5, 0.5, r, cex = cex.cor, font=fonts)
               }
    col.corrgram <- function(ncol){   
       colorRampPalette(c("blue", "lightblue", "red", "darkred"))(ncol)} 
            corrgram(data.full[,c(2:ncol(data.full))], type="data",lower.panel=panel.shadeNtext, 
          upper.panel=NULL, text.panel=panel.txt, col=col.corrgram)
     dev.off()
```

please help me putting colored dendrogram over this correllogram

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Manvendra, 
Just to be sure - you are asking how to use heatmap.2 to plot a correlation matrix? can you give a simple example object that you would like to plot?

Comment: Hi @Tal Gaili,    Thanks for reply, I want this kind of matrix http://yin.che.wisc.edu/images/ProteinMatrix.jpg  but with dendrogram displaying spearman's correlation